# Integral inequalities and change of variables

Tags: probability-distributions, integral-inequality

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be probability density functions defined on $[0,\infty)$.

We have that
$$ \int_{0}^\infty x^n g(x) dx \le \int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) dx \quad {for} \quad n=0,1,\ldots \infty.$$

Can one prove that
$$ \int_{0}^\infty x^{n+1} g(x^2) dx \le \int_0^{\infty} x^{n+1} f(x^2) dx \quad {for} \quad n=0,1,\ldots \infty? \tag{1}$$

Substituting $x=y^2$ in the top equation, I get
$$ \int_{0}^\infty y^{2n} g(y^2) dy^2 \le \int_0^{\infty} y^{2n} f(y^2) dy^2 \quad {for} \quad n=0,1,\ldots \infty.$$
which simplifies to
$$ \int_{0}^\infty y^{2n+1} g(y^2) dy \le \int_0^{\infty} y^{2n+1} f(y^2) dy \quad {for} \quad n=0,1,\ldots \infty,$$
which proves equation (1) for $n$ even.

Can one prove equation (1) for the case where $n$ is an odd number, or is there an altogether simpler way?

Comment: I don't really have much advice as this isn't really my area, but as far as I can tell your last inequality only proves $(1)$ for even $n$.

Comment: Thank you @Fishbane, I will update my question accordingly.